# Azure Logic App Integration Tools in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure, biztalk, azure-logic-apps, x12

I am an experienced BizTalk developer who is now moving on to Azure logic apps.  I have installed Visual Studio 2017 and added the "Azure Logic Apps Tools for Visual Studio" through the **Tools|Extensions and Updates** menu.  However, I don't see an option for creating/editing XML schemas(.xsd files), I don't see the BizTalk EDI X12 schemas and there is no option for creating a map.  What am I missing?  I have searched and searched with no luck.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

XSD & Maps are part of the Azure Integration Account service. You need the Microsoft Azure Logic Apps Enterprise Integration Tools in order to use those. You will see that the mapper is very similar to what you know from the BizTalk-world.

I'm not sure Microsoft Azure Logic Apps Enterprise Integration Tools is already supported in VS 2017. I know it's supported on VS 2015.

On a side note, xsd's and maps created using a BizTalk Server Project will also work fine in an Azure Integration Account and Logic Apps,but might lead to a more complex ALM-story.

Answer (score 0):

Right now **there is no tooling available for Visual Studio 2017**, only for Visual Studio 2015.

The tools are based on the BizTalk components and those components are only available for Visual Studio 2015.

You can download EDI schemas from Open Source Github, but only EANCOM and EDIFACT, X12 messages have been removed due to licensing questions https://github.com/Microsoft/Integration/tree/master/BizTalk%20Server/Schema

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Are you saying that logic apps can't support X12 at this time?

Comment: No, if you obtain the schemas, you can use it, but you have to get the X12 schemas from other site due to licensing questions. For example, you can take from a BizTalk installation of your own.

Comment: I have installed the tools for VS 2015 and I still don't see any options for creating schemas for EDI standard or for creating any kind of a map.  I also can't find any instructions on how to do this.

Comment: Have you installed Microsoft Azure Logic Apps Enterprise Integration Tools for Visual Studio 2015 2.0? Then you have a new project type Logic Apps > Integration Account where you can add schemas and develope maps.

Comment: I finally got it to work.  The .msi file had to be run outside of the VS installer.  The Tools menu and the Visual Studio Installer didn't work me.  Thanks for the help.